# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver even when jar files are placed at classpath

Tags: java, mysql, jar

Trying to Execute this java file from command line without using Maven etc to connect to Mysql with jar files placed at a $HOME/Dependancy/*.jar

```
import java.sql.*;
public class MysqlCon
{
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
                try{
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bpx","romeo","BPXmysql*123");
                Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select name from product_tbl");
                while(rs.next())
                        System.out.println(rs.getString(1)+" Get Product ");
                con.close();
                }catch(Exception e){ System.out.println(e);}
        }
}
```

still getting this error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

tried to get refer previous answers in the similar context ,but all of them refer of adding jar files and add them to the class path while executing which I have already done
Not sure what I am doing wrong

jar files used

```
mysql-5.1.10.jar  mysql-connector-java-5.1.13.jar  mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar
```

Thanks in Advance

cmd line code

```
javac -cp '.:/home/blesson/scripts/utilities/core_java/Dependancy/' /home/blesson/scripts/utilities/core_java/MysqlCon.java
java -cp '.:/home/blesson/scripts/utilities/core_java/Dependancy/' /home/blesson/scripts/utilities/core_java/MysqlCon
```

Comment: You need one and only one JAR file for the MySQL JDBC drivers.  If you put multiple driver JARs on the classpath, bad things could happens. Check the MySQL documentation to figure out which driver JAR you should use ... and preferably download it from the MySQL site or some other place that you can trust not to infest the JAR with malware.

Answer (score 0):

place mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar same folder where your .java file exist
open command line in the same folder or change directory to where your .java file exist

compile

```
javac -cp .:/home/sts0020/Desktop/java/jdbc/mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar YOUR_CLASS_NAME.java
```

run

```
java -cp .:/home/sts0020/Desktop/java/jdbc/mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar YOUR_CLASS_NAME.java
```

Comment: Can the dependancy jar files be packed in a separate folder if its a requirement?